# converting PEP 448 Python 3.5 code to Python 3.4-compatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following function:

```
    def to_url(self):
    return {
        'ass_cls': self.model.__class__.__name__,
        **{local.name: getattr(self.model.src, remote.name)
           for local, remote in self.model.__class__.src.property.local_remote_pairs},
        **{k: v
           for k, v in self.model.__dict__.items()
           if not k.startswith('_') and k != 'src'},
    }
```

How do I convert this piece of code into Python 3.4-compatible?

I believe, the code currently uses [PEP 448 - Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations) right now, which is a Python 3.5 feature.

Comment: What's wrong with it as-is? (aside from the indentation...)

Comment: @MattDMo it's using Python 3.5 features :) It isn't going to work in Python 3.4

Comment: There are **many** ways to do it, here's a one-liner:`dict(ass_cls=1, **dict(dict_comp_1, **dict_comp_2))`. Basically all you need is a flattened dict at the end combined of keys obtained from all the dicts.

Comment: @omtcyf0 perhaps you could highlight *which* features, and/or provide the 3.4 error message, so that every reader doesn't have to figure it out themselves.

Comment: So the 3.5 feature is that nested {} syntax.  The expression would clearer if the dictionary was created separately in one or more expressions.

Comment: @jonrsharpeah, yeah, sorry for that. Sure thing.

Comment: Here is the feature -- Whats new in python 3.5 --[Additional Unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You can't use more than one keyword unpacking argument in Python <3.5

Comment: @BrendanAbel I know. Guess you missed some parenthesis, I am not using two unpacking arguments. Look again. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new [unpacking feature](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations) is what won't work in 3.4.

You'll have to use the older, more verbose method of merging dictionaries.

```
def to_url(self):
    d = {'ass_cls': self.model.__class__.__name__}
    d.update({local.name: getattr(self.model.src, remote.name) 
        for local, remote in self.model.__class__.src.property.local_remote_pairs})
    d.update({k: v for k, v in self.model.__dict__.items()
        if not k.startswith('_') and k != 'src'})
    return d
```

Comment: You could also pass generator expressions (yielding `key, value` 2-tuples) to `update` rather than creating the sub-dictionaries with comprehensions. Not sure if it's any faster (though it should use a bit less peak memory) but it seems more natural to me. Just drop the `{}` and use `(k, v)` instead of `k: v`.